# Datadirect Drivers for Paradox

Tags: database, odbc, paradox

I need to access my data stored in the Paradox database.

I have installed Datadirect drivers for accessing the paradox database and have configured the User DSN and System DSN data source connections as mentioned in all the manuals.

I still am not able to connect to my Paradox database and get :

```
Network Initialization error, Cannot connect to file.
```

I currently have :

```
> Control Panel>Administrative Tools> ODBC Datasource> Drivers> Datadirect Paradox 6.0
```

Is there anyway I can test whether my Datadirect drivers have been installed correctly? I could not find anywhere how to do the same.

Any help or advise on how I can test the the drivers would be very helpful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you find the driver name under `ODBC Datasource> Drivers`, the driver has been installed successfully, the error you got leads to a problem reaching database over the network.

Check your connection string and if the file you pointing is really reachable ...

Comment: The file I am pointing to is located in my C:\. I set the connection to C:\ by creating a ODBC Datasource>User DSN and Odbc datasource>System DSN. I do a "test connection" and it turns out to be successful. Still does not connect. I typed out address manually for any database folder in the explorer window of my machine and it is reachable.